# Django can't load media image if DEBUG = False (WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /media/cache/)

Tags: django

User uploaded media images are not loading unless I have DEBUG set to True in my settings file. I'm getting the following error in my logs:

`WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /media/cache/ae/d2/aed2b5f7dcd26e01a2a9721540ee6e8e.jpg`

That exact folder path does exist locally and that image file does exist. I'm pretty lost what to do from here. I read all the other answers with similar questions and tried everything. If I set DEBUG = True, the images load just fine in both local dev and Heroku environments. Once DEBUG = False, the images don't load in either environment.
Here's my code:

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

#STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [ ... ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

html template:

```
{% load static %}
          {% load thumbnail %}
          {% thumbnail profile.profile_image "168x168" as im %}
          {{im.url}}
          <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}" alt="profile image" class="avatar avatar-xl mb-4">
          {% empty %}
          <img src="{% static 'assets/img/icons/theme/general/user.svg' %}" alt="Confirmation Icon" class="icon bg-primary" data-inject-svg="data-inject-svg">
          {% endthumbnail %}
```

im.url does produce the correct file path to the image. Any ideas? Thanks!